# How to register AndroidLintInspectionBase in IntellijIdea Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm creating a costum Android Lint Inspection and I need to register the inspection, to be run. Where do I need to register it?

I've already tried to register the inspection which provides the inspection inside `plugin.xml` file.

**The actual inspection:**

```
class HardcodedDimensionsInspection : AndroidLintInspectionBase("Hardcoded dimensions", HardcodedDimensDetector.ISSUE) {

    override fun getShortName(): String {
        return "AndroidLintHardcodedDimension"
    }
}
```

**The entry in `plugin.xml` file**

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- Add your extensions here -->

<!--        <inspectionToolProvider implementation="JavaInspectionProvider"/>-->


        <globalInspection shortName="AndroidLintHardcodedDimension" displayName="Hardcoded dimensions"
                          enabledByDefault="true" level="WARNING"
                          implementationClass="HardcodedDimensionsInspection"/>
    </extensions>
```

**The actual detector**

```
class HardcodedDimensDetector : LayoutDetector() {
    override fun getApplicableAttributes(): Collection<String>? {
        return Arrays.asList(
                // Layouts
                ATTR_TEXT
        )
    }

    override fun appliesTo(folderType: ResourceFolderType): Boolean {
        return (folderType == ResourceFolderType.LAYOUT ||
                folderType == ResourceFolderType.MENU ||
                folderType == ResourceFolderType.XML)
    }

    override fun visitAttribute(context: XmlContext, attribute: Attr) {
        val value = attribute.value
    }

    companion object {

        /** The main issue discovered by this detector  */
        @JvmField
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
                id = "HardcodedDimension",
                briefDescription = "Hardcoded dimens",
                explanation = """
                Brief
                """,
                category = Category.I18N,
                priority = 5,
                severity = Severity.ERROR,
                implementation = Implementation(
                        HardcodedDimensDetector::class.java,
                        Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE
                )
        )
    }
}
```

I've expected to hit the breakpoints in any of the functions for **Detector** but the code is never called. Seems like my detector is not registered. Can you please point me to the missing part, is there a class where I should register my `Detector`?

Thank you.

The link to the full project: https://github.com/magicbytes/Android-Lint-Inspection

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious wrong from these snippets. Could you please post on our forum and link to the full sources of your plugin? Thanks. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development

Comment: Thank you @Yann Ceborn for reaching out. I've added the post to the link indicated, and attached a link to the project in Github.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for now, not sure it's the official way to do it. Android Lint has a registry with all the `Issue` classes (built-in), the class is called `LintIdeIssueRegistry`. When it runs the Android Lint, it's looking in this registry for Issue processors. Since the list is hardcoded, we need to inject ours in the list. I'm using the following code for that:

```
val registry = LintIdeIssueRegistry()
val issue = registry.getIssue(HardcodedDimensDetector.ISSUE.id)
if (issue == null) {
   val list = registry.issues as MutableList<Issue>
   list.add(HardcodedDimensDetector.ISSUE)
}
```

Hopefully in future we will have a method called `addIssue` inside the `LintIdeIssueRegistry`.